# Spring Boot 1.4.1 surefire plugin doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to override it from the parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am having trouble with Spring Boot to get a simple application working with tests.  (Using this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) This is my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I had some problems with the version of the surefire plugin included in the spring-boot-starter-parent (version 2.18.1).  When I run it (mvn clean package) I get the following Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project gs-spring-boot: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/DefaultScanResult

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/DefaultScanResult
```

When I looked inside the maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1 jar DefaultScanResult class was not there although it is in maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1.

So what I wanted to do was to override the surefire plugin version to maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1.
I know SpringBoot has a mechanism for overriding versions but there does not appear to be a property for surefire to override.

For instance I looked here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

There are lots of properties for versions but not one for surefire - seems to be hardcoded as 2.18.1

So is there another way I can override it?

I accept it may be hard coded for a reason but wanted to know anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce that with the POM you posted. Make sure you clean before compiling by running `mvn clean package`.

Comment: I did mention on the original post I used mvn clean compile.  Maybe it only happens when you have test files so surefire tries to run them.

Comment: Yes I tested with a simple test file and everything worked fine on my end.